# Interface and metadata errors in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

trying to create First WCF service, but two errors  are not allowing me to go to the next level.

> 1) Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible.
>   Make sure     your service is running and exposing metadata.
>   2) Error:
>   Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:53238/SMSGatewayPortClient.svc If this is a Windows
>   (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>    The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://localhost:53238/SMSGatewayPortClient.svc    The HTML document
>   does not contain Web service discovery information.

Below is my class:

```
namespace WcfService2
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }


        sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request)
        {
            sendMessageResponse1 s = new sendMessageResponse1();
            return s;
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" httpHelpPageEnabled="True" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Error 1   'WcfService2.Service1' does not implement interface member
>   'WcfService2.IService1.sendMessage(WcfService2.sendMessageRequest)'.
>   'WcfService2.Service1.sendMessage(WcfService2.sendMessageRequest)'
>   cannot implement an interface member because it is not
>   public.   c:\users\phanikic\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WcfService2\WcfService2\Service1.svc.cs 12  18

As per my knowledge these errors are because of configurations , and could any body say what would be the changes, to make service run? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make this `sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request)` `public`

Comment: @rene:that error gone by making public, but throwing some other similar error. made all the members as public: Error 1 'WcfService2.Service1' does not implement interface member 'WcfService2.IService1.sendMessage(WcfService2.sendMessageRequest)'

Comment: @Chiranjeevi do not post code in the comments - edit your question instead.